# how to publish mp4 file with av1 codec option to rtmp stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

First, I used h264 codec, but I tried to Change Video Codec to AV1.
using ffmpeg, I want to publish the mp4 file to rtmp stream with av1 codec option.
and I tried this command

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i av1video.mp4 -c:v av1_nvenc -c:a copy -b:v 4M -vf "hwupload_cuda" -f flv "rtmp://[test_server_ip]/app/[my_streamkey]"`

ffmpeg return this.

```
[mp4 @ 000001438fbc8580] muxer does not support non seekable output  
[out#0/mp4 @ 000001438dc6e500] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

also I tried

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i av1video.mp4 -c:v av1_nvenc -c:a copy -b:v 4M -vf "hwupload_cuda" -f flv "rtmp://[test_server_ip]/app/[my_streamkey]"
```

ffmpeg return

```
[flv @ 00000185737c8580] Video codec av1 not compatible with flv
[out#0/flv @ 000001857182e500] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented
Conversion failed!
```

My GPU is NVIDIA GEFORCE 4070 Ti

Is It possible to publish data with av1 codec option to rtmp stream ?
If It can, could you share the ffmpeg commnad?

Comment: 1. My ffmpeg version is 6.0. window OS  

2. I wonder that do i use -f file contanier option use mp4 or flv.

Comment: "Video codec av1 not compatible with flv" means that FLV container doesn't support AV1 video codec. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video), FLV doesn't support AV1 codec. In case there is some extension of FLV that supports AV1, it is not supported by FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Youtube released "AV1 and HEVC" ingest using an updated protocol they are calling "Enhanced RTMP" that allows the AV1 codec to be used. See the project here:

https://github.com/veovera/enhanced-rtmp